# Terminal giving errors instead of running perl script?

Tags: perl

I know that's a vague question, but I'm unsure what the nature of the error is. I'm trying to learn perl but when I try to open the perl script in the directory, it gives me a ton of errors and refuses to open it. But these are scripts I copied from examples, so I don't know how there would be so many problems.

These are the error messages for one script:

> syntax error at atom1perl.pl line 11, near "my "
> Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $name"?) at atom1perl.pl line 11.
> syntax error at atom1perl.pl line 15, near ")

> my "
> Global symbol "$my_info" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $my_info"?) at atom1perl.pl line 15.
> Global symbol "$my_info" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $my_info"?) at atom1perl.pl line 17.
> Execution of atom1perl.pl aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
> (F) Probably means you had a syntax error.  Common reasons include:

> ```
>    A keyword is misspelled.
>    A semicolon is missing.
>    A comma is missing.
>    An opening or closing parenthesis is missing.
>    An opening or closing brace is missing.
>    A closing quote is missing.
> ```

> Often there will be another error message associated with the syntax
> error giving more information.  (Sometimes it helps to turn on -w.)
> The error message itself often tells you where it was in the line when
> it decided to give up.  Sometimes the actual error is several tokens
> before this, because Perl is good at understanding random input.
> Occasionally the line number may be misleading, and once in a blue moon
> the only way to figure out what's triggering the error is to call
> perl -c repeatedly, chopping away half the program each time to see
> if the error went away.  Sort of the cybernetic version of 20 questions.

> Uncaught exception from user code:
> syntax error at atom1perl.pl line 11, near "my "
> Global symbol "$name" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $name"?) at atom1perl.pl line 11.
> syntax error at atom1perl.pl line 15, near ")

> my "
> Global symbol "$my_info" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $my_info"?) at atom1perl.pl line 15.
> Global symbol "$my_info" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $my_info"?) at atom1perl.pl line 17.
> Execution of atom1perl.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

This is the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use feature 'say';

use feature "switch";

print "Hello World\n"

my $name = "X";

my ($age, $street) = (50, "XYZ")

my $my_info = "$name lives on \"$street\"n";

print $my_info
```

It's been the same for other sample scripts, too. I assume the issue is with how I'm opening it, but I don't know any other way.

Comment: `Common reasons include: A semicolon is missing.`  Ding.

Comment: You're right about the missing semicolons! I just added them in and the script still won't open.

Comment: Please edit your post to update your error message and code to show the latest version with the semicolons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please compare corrected code with code you have.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use feature 'say';
use feature 'switch';

print "Hello World\n";

my $name = "X";
my ($age, $street) = (50, "XYZ");
my $my_info = "$name lives on \"$street\"\n";

print $my_info;
```

Output

```
Hello World
X lives on "XYZ"
```